# Why OpenSSL's PKCS7_verify() requires "smimesign" certificate purpose?

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, x509, pkcs#7

Man page for `PKCS7_verify()` states that

`...Each signer's certificate is chain verified using the smimesign purpose...`

Why is exactly this one purpose always required? I understand it so that a signed PKCS7 structure can be used for many things, S/MIME being just one of them.

If my signing certificate does not have `smimeSign` among its `extendedKeyUsage` extensions, `PKCS7_verify()` fails. I'd need to manually adjust the `purpose` in order to do the verification. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply verifying the signature, checking that the signer's certificate is authentic and that the chain leads to a trusted root is not enough. Any verification code also must ensure that the certificate holder was entitled to perform the signing for the particular purpose. The vetting to get a certificate that has `smimeSign` privilege is a lot less stringent than the vetting for, say a code signing certificate.

Imagine a software development company where every employee has been issued a certificate for the purpose of email signing and encryption. This company also releases a software product, and provides a PKCS#7 signed distribution package of its product. If PKCS#7 verification functions did not check the purpose of the signing certificate (in this case we'd want `codesign`), a bad actor in the employ of the company could create a compromised version of the software product, and sign it with their E-Mail certificate (which only has the purpose `smimesign`.)

In the case of OpenSSL's `pkcs7_verify()`, the API was designed to imply a purpose instead of explicitly requiring one to be passed in, and `smimeSign` was chosen as default. I'm guessing that since S/MIME is the most common use of PKCS#7, it made sense, and it allows someone to verify PKCS#7 in most use cases without having to learn about `extendedKeyUsage`.

[Below my original answer, to address your pre-edit question '*Can I specify that I want to verify a signature in a PKCS7 against some other purpose'*:]

A certificate can contain an (optional) attribute called "Extended Key Usage". This attribute is used to indicate what the certificate is allowed to be used for. Some possible X509.v3 usages are:

- serverAuthentication
- clientAuthentication
- codeSigning
- emailProtection
- ipSecEndSystem
- ipSecTunnel
- timeStamping
- ocspSigning
- smartCardLogin
- pkiPeerAuth

You can check the [x509v3_config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/apps/x509v3_config.html) man page for the key usage flags that openssl is aware of.

PKCS#7 is a general container format that allows for both signing and or encrypting the content of the container. S/MIME uses PKCS#7 for signing and/or encrypting email message, and in that case, the certificate being used should have the emailProtection usage.

If you wanted to distribute some code, and you want to make sure that the recipient can verify that the distribution is from you, and unaltered, you could use PKCS#7 to distribute, and in that case your certificate should have the codeSigning enhanced key usage attribute.
It is possible for a certificate to have multiple key usages, but in general it's a good idea to have a separate key (and therefore certificate) for different usage types.

Openssl, on the command line, supports specifying the desired purpose of the certificate when using the "openssl smime" command. For example,

```
    openssl smime -verify -in myfile.p7b -inform DER -out my-p7-content -purpose any
```

will verify the signature in the file 'my file.p7p', it will write the content of the PKCS#7 container in file 'my-p7-content' and it will accept any valid certificate, no matter what its indicated purpose is. (-purpose any). Please note that the openssl man page for smime does not list the -purpose switch as an option, but it is indeed supported.

Since you quote the PKCS7_verify API documentation, programmatically, you can specify the purpose via the [X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_purpose](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/crypto/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags.html) method when you're setting up your X509_STORE object. The following fragment should give you an idea of the process:

```
X509_STORE store;
int purpose;

store = X509_STORE_new();
verify_params = X509_Store_get0_param(store);
purpose = X509_PURPOSE_get_by_sname("sslclient");
X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_purpose(verify_params, purpose)
...
PKCS7_verify(..., store, ...);
```

This will set the purpose to SSL Client when verifying.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer; but my question was not about **how to change** verification purposes. It was about **why am I supposed to do it**. (I updated the question to be more specific on this.) My use case is in fact exactly what you refer to: PKCS#7 is used for signing software, and the signing certificate has `KeyUsage=critical, digitalSignature` and `ExtendedKeyUsage=codeSigning`. `PKCS7_verify()` fails on signature made with this certificate (and succeeds if I add `smimesign` purpose). Why does this function always require one particular `purpose`?

Comment: @user3608247 I've updated my answer to address your edited question. I left the original answer on the 'how' in since it's not too obvious for the casual user how to do it programmatically and it might be useful to someone.